# trouble with JavaScript innerHTML to image replacement

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to JavaScript and am doing a project for a class. I want to create an Easter egg somewhere on the page that when clicked changes the whole page code to a single image. This is my code just to test out the concept:

```
<div id = "all">
    <p>The button below changes the whole page.</p>

    <button type = "button" onclick = "changePage()">Click Here</button>
</div>

<script>
    function changePage()
    {
        document.getElementById("all").innerHTML = "<img src = "stop.jpg" />";
    }
</script>
```

The content isn't replaced by the image stop.jpg, however when I change the line to:

```
document.getElementById("all").innerHTML = "<h1>Whatever</h1>";
```

The code changes to the simple heading with no problems. Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Didn't you notice that quotes are repeating? You should wrap your img with another quotes:

```
'<img src = "stop.jpg" />'
```

Or escape them

```
"<img src = \"stop.jpg\" />"
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your quoting. The double quotes around the `stop.jpg` URL are ending the string that begins with `<img`. You need to use single quotes or escape the quotes:

```
document.getElementById("all").innerHTML = "<img src = 'stop.jpg' />";

document.getElementById("all").innerHTML = "<img src = \"stop.jpg\" />";
```

Didn't you get a syntax error in the Javascript console? Or notice the changed color in SO's syntax highlighting?

Comment: Oh OK. Wow I feel uneducated now. I don't know why I didn't think of that. Thanks, works now! :D

Comment: Haha sorry, just commented on the first one I read. Thanks to you both! And no I didn't get a syntax error, I'm simply using Notepad++ to create/edit my files.

Comment: You should have gotten a syntax error when you tried to load your page. Don't you check the Javascript console in the browser when you're trying to debug Javascript?

Comment: No, I don't know about the javascript console. When I said I'm new, I meant like just started using JavaScript this morning. lol